# Get list of items in one list that are not in another

Tags: javascript

I have two comma separated lists, the first is a list of possible values, and the second is a list of "selected" values. I need to create a list of all of the items in the first list that do not exists in the second list.

I could just split the first list into an array and use a "for" to go through the list using a string_pos to see if the first list item is contained in the second, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Turn the second list into an object whose properties are its elements. Then loop through the first list, checking whether they're in the object.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the possible list.

if the lists are strings, split or match them to get arrays.

```
var possible=[1,2,3,4],
selected=[2,4];

var unchosen=possible.filter(function(itm){
  return selected.indexOf(itm)==-1;
});

unchosen

/*  returned value: (Array)
1,3
*/
```

Comment: filter is new in ES5 and thus may need to be polyfilled for IE8 and older, you should have mentioned that fact.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the best possible way, this is what you have to do

1. Convert the list to be checked, to an object, in liner time. Because, objects are technically hashtables, which offer faster lookups O(1)).
2. Then, iterate over the first list and check if the current element is there in the object or not. If it is not there, add it to the result.

   ```
   var list1 = [1, 2, 3], list2 = [1, 2], dict2 = {};

   list2.forEach(function(item) {
       dict2[item] = true;
   });

   var result = list1.reduce(function(prev, current) {
       if (dict2.hasOwnProperty(current) === false) {
           prev.push(current);
       }
       return prev;
   }, [])


   console.log(result);
   ```

**Output**

```
[ 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is definitely to split the two comma separated lists into arrays of strings. Assume that they are formatted fairly reasonably, you can do this with

```
possible_values = possible_string.split(/,\s?/) //split on commas with a possible space
selected_values = selected_string.split(/,\s?/)
```

If you are willing to use outside libraries, [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has a perfect function for this. The operation you are describing is the set difference operator, which is the [difference function](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) in underscore.

The result you want is the return value of calling

```
_.difference(possible_values, selected_values)
```